# How to make sure to reflect all the Excel files

Tags: python, word-cloud

```
"""
Python script to generate word cloud image.
Author - Anurag Rana
Read more on - https://www.pythoncircle.com
"""

from wordcloud import WordCloud
import pandas as pd

# image configurations
background_color = "#101010"
height = 720
width = 1080

with open("stopword.txt", "r", encoding='UTF8') as f:
    stop_words = f.read().split()

# Read a text file and calculate frequency of words in it
text=pd.read_excel('crawling.xlsx')
words=text

data = dict()

for word in words:
    word = word.lower()
    if word in stop_words:
        continue

    data[word] = data.get(word, 0) + 1

word_cloud = WordCloud(
    font_path='NanumBarunGothic.otf',
    background_color=background_color,
    width=width,
    height=height
)

word_cloud.generate_from_frequencies(data)
word_cloud.to_file('image.png')
```

text=pd.read_excel('crawling.xlsx') 
This prints only part of Excel.

And when I created a word cloud, I got bad results.
[image]

I want to create a word cloud that reads all the Excel files and reflects the contents.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this can help you [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-word-cloud-python/)

Comment: It helpful so much

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"crawling.xlsx", encoding="UTF8")

comment_words = ''

for val in df.CONTENT: #CONTENT is the name of first column

    val = str(val)

 okt=Okt()
    noun=okt.nouns(val)

    for i,v in enumerate(noun):
        if len(v)<2:
            noun.pop(i)

    comment_words += " ".join(noun) + " "

word_cloud.generate_from_frequencies(comment_words)
```